# Magento 2 Checkout Billing Step Error 'Shipping Address is not set'

Tags: php, magento2, checkout, magento2.1

On last step of my Magento 2.1 checkout (billing step) when I Proceed I get a validation error 'Shipping Address is not set'. I have already entered the shipping address and it is also visible in side bar on billing step.

[image]

I have tried all similar questions on stackoverflow.
I have clear cache, session etc.

Note: I have an extra step on my checkout. I added a new first step which shows cart items. Step navigation seems to be working fine and data seems to be flowing between steps smoothly.

Anyone has any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I have been able to identify the cause of the issue. I have moved the shipping method inputs to a new KO component that appears on top of each step. This means that I have removed the shipping method section from the shipping.html template. If I add them back to the template then there is no error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason for this. It was actually a very misleading error and had got nothing to do with Shipping Address.

I am using Braintree for payment integration and there was some issue with my Sandbox account API key. I created new API keys and after that the billing step did not show me the "Address is not set" error.